# Spawning pathfinder neighbours

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding, neighbours

I am trying to spawn the neighbours of my path finder but when doing so the original path (path) blue also becomes covered up. I have tried switching of the order of spawn but this does not seem to help the problem. Quite new to Unity and would appreciate any insight into how I might go about spawning the path the neighbours without losing the original blue path.

Obtaining path neighbours; spawning the path + neighbours

```
for (int i = 1; i < path.Count; i++)
{
    var pathCellPosition = path[i];
    pathCellPosition.Position = new Vector3(pathCellPosition.Position.x, pathPrefab.transform.position.y, pathCellPosition.Position.z);
   
    List<Node> neighbours = GetNeighbours(pathCellPosition);
    var p = Instantiate(pathPrefab, pathCellPosition.Position, Quaternion.identity, PathCells);

    foreach (Node n in neighbours)
    {
        neighbourPrefab.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = n.Cost.ToString();
        Instantiate(neighbourPrefab, n.Position, Quaternion.identity, p.transform);            
    }

}
```

Original path
[image]

Path getting covered by neighbours
[image]

### Implemented suggestions fixing part of the problem

The tiles around now seem to appear but when applying the same solution to implement neighbours of neighbours it seems to cause an overlap with the original neighbouring nodes.
[image]

Code changes:

```
    HashSet<Node> visitedNodes = new HashSet<Node>();
    for (int i = 1; i < path.Count; i++)
    {
        var pathCellPosition = path[i];
        visitedNodes.Add(path[i]);
        pathCellPosition.Position = new Vector3(pathCellPosition.Position.x, pathPrefab.transform.position.y, pathCellPosition.Position.z);
       
        List<Node> neighbours = GetNeighbours(path[i]);

        int fCost = DistanceFromStart(pathCellPosition) + HCostDistanceFromEndNode(pathCellPosition) + pathCellPosition.Cost;
        pathPrefab.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = fCost.ToString();
        var p = Instantiate(pathPrefab, pathCellPosition.Position, Quaternion.identity, PathCells);

        for(int x = 0; x < neighbours.Count; x++)
        {
            var node = neighbours[x];
            if (visitedNodes.Contains(node))
            {
                continue;
            }
            visitedNodes.Add(node);
            fCost = DistanceFromStart(node) + HCostDistanceFromEndNode(node) + node.Cost;
            neighbourPrefab.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = fCost.ToString();
            Instantiate(neighbourPrefab, node.Position, Quaternion.identity, p.transform);

            List<Node> NeighBourOfNeighbourNodes = GetNeighbours(node);

            if(NeighBourOfNeighbourNodes.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < NeighBourOfNeighbourNodes.Count; y++)
                {
                    var neighbourNode = NeighBourOfNeighbourNodes[y];
                    if (visitedNodes.Contains(neighbourNode))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    visitedNodes.Add(neighbourNode);
                    fCost = DistanceFromStart(neighbourNode) + HCostDistanceFromEndNode(neighbourNode) + neighbourNode.Cost;
                    nofn.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = fCost.ToString();
                    Instantiate(nofn, neighbourNode.Position, Quaternion.identity, p.transform);
                }
            }
        }
```

If I don't draw neighbour of neighbours, this looks right. But if I do neighbour of neighbours the purple ones don't appear as much as they should.
Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical simple solution is to check if the node is part of the path before adding. A HashSet can be good for this, but you will need something that can be reliably compared.

Perhaps something like this:

```
var visitedNodes = new HashSet<Node>(path);
for (int i = 1; i < path.Count; i++)
{
    var pathCellPosition = path[i];
    pathCellPosition.Position = new Vector3(pathCellPosition.Position.x, pathPrefab.transform.position.y, pathCellPosition.Position.z);
   
    List<Node> neighbours = GetNeighbours(pathCellPosition);
    var p = Instantiate(pathPrefab, pathCellPosition.Position, Quaternion.identity, PathCells);

    foreach (Node n in neighbours)
    {
        if(visitedNodes.Contains(n))
             continue;
         visitedNodes.Add(n);
        neighbourPrefab.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = n.Cost.ToString();
        Instantiate(neighbourPrefab, n.Position, Quaternion.identity, p.transform);            
    }

}
```

You can also use the same approach to ensure a neighbour is not added twice.

If you want multiple levels from the node you might need to do something like a breath first search, ideally keeping track of the distance from the original path. The following generic code should traverse the graph in a breadth first manner, just use the `path` as the first parameter, and the `GetNeighbours` method for the second.

```
public static IEnumerable<(T Node, int Distance)> GetNeighborsWithDistance<T>(IEnumerable<T> self, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector)
{
    var stack = new Queue<(T Node, int Distance)>();
    var visited = new HashSet<T>();
    foreach (var node in self)
    {
        stack.Enqueue((node, 0));
    }
    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var current = stack.Dequeue();
        if(visited.Contains(current.Node))
            continue;

        yield return current;
        visited.Add(current.Node);
        foreach (var child in selector(current.Node))
        {
            stack.Enqueue((child, current.Distance+ 1));
        }
    }
}
```

This should be guaranteed to return nodes in order of distance from the original path, so just do `.TakeWhile(p => p.Distance < DesiredDistanceFromOriginalPath)` to get as many nodes as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This fixed the neighbouring node issue for me but when I try to spawn neighbours of neighbours, those new neighbours end up overlapping the previous neighbours. I'm unsure why. I feel your solution should have fixed that issue.

Comment: @Krellex See edit, you probably just need to add neighbor nodes to the hashSet.

Comment: Thanks for getting back again. I updated as you suggested but it seems to prioritise neighbour of neighbours as the original neighbours. I updated the post to show images and code

Comment: @Krellex your edit should probably be a new question, but I have added a section about getting nodes at an arbitrary distance from the original path.